# Making world grid with angle in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, latitude-longitude

I need to make a world map with a grid that have a angle like in this map[image]

I look into it and find that I can add a grid in the print composer [image]
I have succeeded to change the grid distance in the settings [image]

I have not succeeded to make the required angle, and I tried to use the Robinson projection [image]

I also tried to upload Graticules file from [OSM](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors), but the grid is still without a angle in "WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator" and in "World_Robinson" as wall[image]

Can anyone help me with this topic?

Comment: You need to set your projection to Robinson in QGIS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_projection http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Is the project CRS also 4326?

Comment: Yes, it is 4326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Steven Kay](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/55203/steven-kay) and the others helped me to figure it out.

First of all you need to download the grid from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors).

At the first step you will have a grid lines that need to change into the "world_Robinson" CRS[image]
Then go to the "Set Project from layer" [image].
In this interim step the base layer will be with a angel and the grid will be out of place[image]
Know you need to change back the CRS of the grid into "WGS 84" or any other CRS you are using and you will get a angle grid map [image]

Comment: There is absolutely no need to give your grid a wrong CRS and then switch it back! Just load the grid and set your project CRS to "world_robinson". That's it, tried in myself.

Comment: I have tried it your way and it did not work for me. Can you add some more data?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think composer grids will work with Robinson as the map units for that projection are meters.

Composer grids don't currently offer degrees as an option for grid spacing on such projections, just map units and paper units (as of QGIS 2.18).

Your best bet is to use Robinson projection as suggested by Mapperz, but use graticule lines instead.

You can get these ready-made from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors). Use the 1:10m version as these are more detailed and give a smoother result when you change the projection...

You may find with this projection that the antimeridian (the curved outer edges at 180E/W) are missing (or don't get drawn).

In that case, use the included WGS84 bounding box polygon to give the edge (can also use this to colour in the oceans)...

[image]

Comment: I have upload this file  from OSM and the map is stile without a angle

Comment: you need to set on-the-fly projection to Robinson. See [the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html) for how to do this

Comment: @NitzanMatan I did assume that this was Natural Earth Data.. Steven's Answer is the same method I would apply.