# Is there a way to change the display of a raster file into a Robinson projection in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I had [asked and answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243559/making-world-grid-with-angle-in-qgis) about the way to make a world map with an angle.

Now I am trying to make the same thing with a raster file.

I had changed the raster CRS, but I did not succeed to make him appear with the shp files

[image].

When the raster CRS is set on WGS 84 it's display separately from the other layers

[image].

Actually I am not sure if this is even possible to do.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and tags to reference the software you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your linked Q/A...well, I get the impression that you slightly screwed up your projections here... ,)
My suggestion:

- get a fresh copy of your data and check the websites for the data's
  metainfo on it's CRS
- if QGIS asks you on import, set it to THAT projection, if not,
  leave it
- set QGIS' [on-the-fly-reprojection](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#define-on-the-fly-otf-reprojection) (NOT the layer's CRS!) to 'world_robinson' (EPSG: 54030) and you should see all layers with a spherical appearance

Why? That data is stored with it's defined projection when you download it. To change that, one need to (mathematically) transform that projection, not simply set it to another one (like you seem to have done, based on your linked Q/A). If you simply set it to a wrong projection, it alters the data's CRS metadata and the layer will most certainly show up at a wrong position.
QGIS offers a flexible on-the-fly-reprojection, which will display all layers in the specified projection wihtout touching the data's CRS.
Reproducing what you have done to the data's CRS would take longer than simply downloading a fresh copy I reckon...

Try it.